# Does anyone have a good way to allow a Necromancer to summon more powerful undead at the cost of summoning less of them?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, necromancy, action-economy

I have a Necromancer that is starting to get a decent size army of undead going. It works great, he mainly uses his other spells to fill the support/buff/debuff role and uses the undead as his main source of damage. The only downside is it is starting to slow down combat.

Does anyone have any good homebrew/ house-rules they use to let the Necromancer summon stronger undead but less of them to keep combat flowing?

Comment: If you're interested in homebrew or 3rd party solutions, what options have you found so far?  Have you discussed ideas with your DM?

Comment: My DM basically said if I found something he would look it over. So far I have found people either revamping the class features or making a whole separate Necromancer class but nothing about my specific question.

Comment: @Luck: [Don't answer in comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments)

Comment: You might get this question reopened if you define what you are looking for in a good answer

Comment: @V2Blast Then unlock the question. There are at least two of us offering answers as the question stands, "backed up" with rules from other systems. This is not attracting primarily opinion based answers. But, if people are really concerned about the word "good" (which is ubiquitous with asking for an answer in general), then simply edit it out.

Comment: In its current state this question runs afoul of [our questions to avoid asking guidelines](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and isn't suitable for our site. We work best when a question can have a single best or correct answer. This one is surveying for an arbitrary unbounded collection of homebrew options where every answer will be equally valid. You can instead ask this question [on a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449). We could facilitate a question about how to get the strongest, fewest undead within the rules, as that's more tightly scoped